# Uploading File Using jQuery Submit Method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a Html `Form` with several `FileUpload` elements, which I want to submit it with jQuery `submit` method, The problem is when the Form submitted It does not send those `Files` which I want to upload. I don't know what is the problem and How should I solve that. The following code shows what is going on my code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Personel", new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   <input type="file" id="personelPhoto" name="personelPhoto" />
}

if (form["personelPhoto"] != null)
{
   // Request's files count is 0 
}
```

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: It is simple `$('form').submit();`

Comment: Could you show the full method serving that post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a generic form submit and have the below as your backend c#(4.0) code it should work

```
 if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
{

  for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
  {
    HttpPostedFileBase hpfTest = Request.Files[i] as HttpPostedFileBase;
    if (hpfTest.ContentLength == 0)
        continue;
    string savedFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Files\\",Request.Form["name"]);    
    hpfTest.SaveAs(savedFileName);  
  }
}
```

Or you could use the "HttpFileCollection" in other versions of .net

```
HttpFileCollection files = Context.Request.Files;
files[0].SaveAs();
```